# Date conversion issue from sql to C# using bootstrap

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have following date in my sql

```
2017-04-16 00:00:00.000
```

I use following code in my C#

```
txtODR.Text = dsSurveyTab.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Order_Recieved_Date"].ToString();
```

I also have bootstrap in frontend and use following code

```
 $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({ format: 'DD/MM/YYYY' });
    });
```

I am not able to pass correct format which bootstrap expects in front end. What is the correct way of doing in C# (server side) code. I need to display as

```
16/04/2017
```

Comment: Where are you setting the date for the date time picker?? There should be a config like `date: new Date("2017-04-16")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done with following code and It works. Thanks

```
string date = dsSurveyTab.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Order_Recieved_Date"].ToString();
txtODR.Text = DateTime.Parse(date).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Comment: I hope your `Order_Recieved_Date` column has a `datetime` type. Then you can cast the value to `DateTime`, instead of using ToString and Parse. `DateTime date = (DateTime)dsSurveyTab.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Order_Recieved_Date"];`